# gmail drive access token expired

Tags: python, api, gmail, client, access-token

i write a code to upload the files from my local pc to my gmail drive i got the acess token for that and this is my code it's work okay but the token is expired after short time :

```
def upload_1():

    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer #acess token"} #put ur access token after the word 'Bearer '
    qassam = glob.glob("/root/Downloads/*.pdf")
    for i in qassam:
        qassam = "\n".join(qassam)  
        print i


        para = {
            "name": (i), #file name to be uploaded
            "parents": ["folderid"] # make a folder on drive in which you want to upload files; then open that folder; the last thing in present url will be folder id
        }
        files = {
            'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
            'file': ('application/zip',open(i, "rb")) # replace 'application/zip' by 'image/png' for png images; similarly 'image/jpeg' (also replace your file name)
        }
        r = requests.post(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
            headers=headers,
            files=files
        )
        print(r.text)


upload_1()
```

is there anyway to refresh my access token after expired without opening a webpage and ....etc , i mean i need to do it from python

Comment: If you have a refresh token, you can retrieve new access token using it when the access token was expired. In that case, it is not required to open the web page.

Comment: I dont understand can u explain more , thank u

Comment: Is this useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline If I misunderstand your question, could you please tell me?

Comment: i dont know there is no full info there ... i write a script to take a backup auto but this script is stop working after 1 hour because the access token is expired !! and i should go to the gmail OAuth playground and copy the new one and replace it manually in the script !! i dont need that i need to do this auto by python

Comment: I apologize that the document and my comment were not useful for your situation.

Comment: no problem my friend

Comment: any help please ??